# how to start a azure web site with network settings

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles, couchbase, azure-virtual-network

i have couchbase cluster deployed on azure service, i have a website that should connect to that cluster. right now what i managed to do is set up a service deploy my web app into it and run the service in my vlan network setting, i did that following this howto : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jimoneil/archive/2012/06/16/couchbase-on-azure-creating-virtual-machines.aspx

what i am interested is to user Azure web site instances and not use a regular service.

would appriciate if someone can guide me how to do it. what i have defied so far is a network with 2 subnet like the link say and its all working on it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Currently (as of December 2013) Azure Web Sites do not support Virtual Network. So your only solution is to have your web site deployed into Cloud Service. Probably we will see Virtual Network support for Windows Azure web sites in the future.

A possible work around is to expose your couchbase to the Internet with an Input Endpoint. You can then use the XXx.cloudapp.net from the Azure Web Site to connect to the CouchBase cluster. Then you will have to worry a bit about who can connect to your CouchBase. You could make some assumptions and only allow Azude Data Centre resources to connect to your Endpoint by [setting ACL](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2013/08/31/weekend-scripter-creating-acls-for-windows-azure-endpoints-part-1-of-2.aspx). Not perfect but at least something - limits the attack surface to only a sub-set of the whole Internet. You can try assessing the [Windows Azure Data Center IP Range](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dn175718.aspx) document.

Comment: I have been trying to set couchbase that is open to the internet for 2 days and failed. i am not sure if the issue is couchbase azure or both of them. any chance you know someone who did it ?